# Is there any repository with Rails inflection files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

So, Rails has some preexisting inflection rules set for English ([see source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/92f567ab30f240a1de152061a6eee76ca6c4da86/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflections.rb)).

But is there any repository with inflections for other languages ?

I am currently looking for :nl and :fr inflections, but other languages may be usefull as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few

https://github.com/davidcelis/inflections

https://github.com/archan937/rich_pluralization

I haven't used them myself so can't vouch for them